# how can i use VolumeShaper to add transactions to media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

For adding different transactions like fade in, fade out to volume bar and seek bar in media player, we can use *VolumeShaper* . Can someone help by elaborating how can we add transactions by VolumeShaper in media player.